# what is the command to dump h264/rtp stream into a file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

I would like to know how to to dump h264/rtp stream video into a file using ffmpeg? I couldn't find any related information for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp://224.0.1.2:5004 -c copy \
   -f segment -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_time 900 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 \
   out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mkv
```

This will stream from the multicast source at `224.0.1.2` on port `5004` and save the output to `out-xxx.mkv` where `xxx` is the current time and date.  The `segment` options will cause a new file to be started every 900 seconds (15 minutes).